# How to enable Android permissions in Android M with out user concern

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am building apk with L code base  , this app uses android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE ,it is working fine in M devices also .

But when i build same app with same permission ,android M prompts for User concern  ,is there any way to by enable these permission without user concern .

My app is system  app .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use any new feature of Android API 23, It's not possible.

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. This approach streamlines the app install process, since the user does not need to grant permissions when they install or update the app. It also gives the user more control over the app's functionality; for example, a user could choose to give a camera app access to the camera but not to the device location. The user can revoke the permissions at any time, by going to the app's Settings screen.

In other case you can downgrade the Android API to 22 but It's not recommended...

You should change your `build.gradle` from something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your.app.id"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
}
```

to something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "you.app.id"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
}
```

Remember to compile only android library version 22 or lower in dependencies like this one `'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'`

Comment: Hi thanks a lot  for your response . yes i want to use finger print api . so it seems i have to handle those permission as google application are handling  . like launcher .thanks for your support